# Multirow alignment issues

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

I am sick of correcting the alignment of the last two columns and its multirows

I want

```
21 dimensions reduced to 9 dimensions
```

comes exactly side by side to

```
Combine accuracy
of 9 dimensional reduced 
Feature Vector is 80\%
```

SIMILARLY

```
9 dimensions Further
reduced to 7 dimensions
```

comes side by side to

```
Combine accuracy
of 7 dimensional reduced    
Feature Vector is 88\%
```

SIMILARLY same for the last "row"

[image: Output image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{array} % loaded twice
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}% added, for rothead
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, tabu}%merged in one line
%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % not used
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% in this table is better use this definition
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
  \settowidth\rotheadsize{DIMENSIONS}
  \renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering} 
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \centering
  \caption{Extreme Learning Machine(ELM) with kernel classifier accuracy of
  combine reduced feature vectors whose individual classifier accuracy was low}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|r|C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|}
    \hline 
    Algorithm
    & Dimension
        &  \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead{ADD THESE\\ DIMENSIONS}}
            & Total after Adding Dimensions
                & Classifier
                    & Dimension Reduction Technique
                        & Reduced Dimension
                            & Accuracy  \\ 
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-8}
LBP & 4D    &
              & \multirow{5}{=}{4D + 6D + 4D\\ + 3D + 4D = 21D}
                 & \multirow{5}{=}{ELM with RBF kernel}
                     & \multirow{4}{=}{Eigenvalue as Dimension Estimator,
                                          PCA as Dimension Reduction}
                         & \multirow{4}{=}{21 dimensions reduced to 9 
dimensions}                                        \newline
                               & \multirow{4}{=}{Combine accuracy
                                                 of 9 dimensional reduced 
                                                 Feature Vector is 
80\%}\smallskip\newline \\
    \cline{1-2}
RGLBP  & 6D    &   &   &   &  &\multirow{5}{=}{9 dimensions Further
                                                  reduced to 7 dimensions} 
                                           &\multirow{5}{=}{Combine accuracy
                                                           of 7 dimensional 
reduced    
                                                           Feature Vector is 
88\% } \newline       \\
    \cline{1-2}
BDIP   & 4D    &   &   &   &   &\multirow{7}{=}{7 dimensions Further
                                                  reduced to 6 dimensions}    
                                    &\multirow{7}{=}{Combine accuracy of 6 
                                                   dimensional reduced 
                                                   Feature Vector is 100\% }\newline   \\
    \cline{1-2} 
HOG      & 3D    &   &   &    &   &   &   \\
    \cline{1-2} 
Combine and     & 4D    &   &   &    &   &   &    \\ 
reduced fv of   &       &   &   &       &   &   &  \\ 
poor individual  &       &   &   &       &   &   & \\   
 accuracy algorithms   &       &   &   &       &   &   & \\  
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:table6}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the contents of the last two columns be somehow aligned with the entries in the first column? What does 'exactly side by side'  mean: vertically centered, top alignes, bottom aligned?

Comment: "21 dimensions .." would by default have lined up with "Combine accuracy...." but you have used `m` column type rather than `p` so the two paragraphs are vertically centred, so as they have different lengths naturally their first lines do not align any more. LaTeX just does what you ask it to do, perhaps you want `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%` but hard to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going crazy with `\multirow` alignment, I think your desired output could be more easily achieved by some `tabular`s within `tabular`s.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% in this table is better use this definition
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Extreme Learning Machine(ELM) with kernel classifier accuracy of
  combine reduced feature vectors whose individual classifier accuracy was 
  low\label{table:table6}}
\begin{tabular}{|L{2cm}|L{1.3cm}|r|C{2.2cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|} 
    \hline 
    Algorithm
    & Dimension
        &   & Total after Adding Dimensions
                & Classifier
                    & Dimension Reduction Technique
                        & Reduced Dimension
                            & Accuracy  \\ 
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{% first "sub"-table
            \begin{tabular}{|L{2cm}|L{1.3cm}|}
                LBP & 4D  \\[4.1pt]
                \hline
                RGLBP  & 6D  \\[4.1pt]
                 \hline
                BDIP   & 4D \\[4.1pt]
                \hline
                HOG      & 3D \\[4.1pt]
                \hline
                Combine and reduced fv of  poor individual accuracy algorithms & 4D \\
            \end{tabular}%
            }
        & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{ADD THESE\\ DIMENSIONS}}
            & \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{% second "sub"-table
            \begin{tabular}{C{2.2cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|}
                \makecell{4D + 6D + 4D\\ + 3D + 4D = 21D} 
                    & ELM with RBF kernel 
                        & Eigenvalue as Dimension Estimator, PCA as Dimension Reduction
                            & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{% third "sub"-table (sub-table of the second sub-table)
                                \begin{tabular}{P{2cm}|P{2.5cm}|}
                                    21 dimensions reduced to 9 dimensions
                                        & Combine accuracy of 9 dimensional reduced Feature Vector is 80\% \\
                                    9 dimensions Further reduced to 7 dimensions
                                        & Combine accuracy of 7 dimensional reduced Feature Vector is 88\% \\
                                    7 dimensions Further reduced to 6 dimensions
                                        & Combine accuracy of 6 dimensional reduced Feature Vector is 100\%  \\
                                \end{tabular}%
                                }
            \end{tabular}
            } \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]